# Input different values into set without using extra variable (C++)

Tags: c++, variables, stl, set

I want to store values into set without using extra variable.

```
int n,x;
set<int> s;
cin>>n;
for(int i=0;i<n;i++)
{
    cin >> x;
    s.insert(x);
}
```

This is what i have been doing till now, was wondering if i could remove x, as this variable is useless.

I am new to C++. Forgive me if my doubt is very naive.

Answer (score 0):

> was wondering if i could remove x

Sure.

```
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>
#include <iterator>
#include <set>

int main() {
  std::set<int> s;
  int n;
  std::cin >> n;
  std::copy_n(std::istream_iterator<int>{std::cin}, n,
              std::inserter(s, s.begin()));
}
```